# Registering the AppAsset in Yii with Smarty

Tags: php, yii, smarty, yii2

I am using Yii2 with Smarty, but I am having trouble registering the AppAsset.

In the .PHP file the following code is executed:

```
AppAsset::register($this);
```

Somewhere in the comments of the Smarty code I found that the 'use' statement is as follows;

```
{use class="backend\assets\AppAsset"}
```

So far, so good. Except now the issue I am having is translating the PHP code to Smarty-compatible code. This is what I have now:

```
{AppAsset::register($this)}
```

This triggers an error, sadly.

```
Object of class backend\assets\AppAsset could not be converted to string
```

Any ideas how I manage this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the asset section here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-template-engines.html#assets

```
{use class="yii\web\JqueryAsset"}
{JqueryAsset::register($this)|void}
```

Comment: This refers to the Twig-section. I am trying to work with Smarty.

Comment: Scroll to the smarty section: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-template-engines.html#smarty I mean RTFM